# How to loop all the questions in pivot table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pivot-table

I am working on a survey and the data looks like this:

```
ID    Q1    Q2    Q3    Gender    Age    Dep    Ethnicity
001   Y      N    Y      F         22     IT        W
002   N      Y    Y      M         35     HR        W
003   Y      N    N      F         20     IT        A
004   Y      N    Y      M         54     OPRE      B
005   Y      N    Y      M         42     OPRE      B
```

Now, I'd like to add two indexes Dep and Gender to create a table like:

```
Question  Dep   Response  #M   #F    %M  %F 
     Q1     IT    Y        0    2     0  100
            IT    N        0    0     0   0
            HR    Y        0    0     0   0
            HR    N        1    0     100 0 
            OPRE  Y        2    0     100 0
            OPRE  N        0    0     0   0  
     Q2     IT    Y        0    0     0   0
            IT    N        0    2     0   100
            HR    Y        1    0     100 0
            HR    N        0    0     0   0 
            OPRE  Y        0    0     0   0
            OPRE  N        2    0     100 0
     Q3 ......
```

My codes are like this:

```
df2=df[['ID','Gender','Dep', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3' ]].melt(
['ID','Gender', 'Dep'],  var_name='question', value_name='response').pivot_table(
index=[ 'question','Dep','response'], 
columns='Gender',
values='ID', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

If I have more questions, I don't want to copy and paste all the Qs in the dataframe, instead I'd like to have a loop which can go over all the questions.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you need zero lines? IT and "N" had no response in Q1 for example

Comment: Yes. I need to keep them to create graphs.

Comment: I have a solution that gives you the Department, but the short coming being that I don't have a zero row, since its not in the data

Comment: Oh, I am thinking about a for loop to go over the questions. Can't you use fillna(0) to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='Q', i=['ID', 'Dep', 'Ethnicity'], j='Question')
         .reset_index().rename(columns={'Q': 'Response'}).assign(Count=1)
         .pivot_table('Count', ['Question', 'Dep', 'Response'], 'Gender', 
                      fill_value=0, aggfunc='count'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
Gender                  F  M
Question Dep  Response      
1        HR   N         0  1
         IT   Y         2  0
         OPRE Y         0  2
2        HR   Y         0  1
         IT   N         2  0
         OPRE N         0  2
3        HR   Y         0  1
         IT   N         1  0
              Y         1  0
         OPRE Y         0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to keep the 0 rows by melting to long form as you're doing, converting the Response to a pd.Categorical, and then groupbing and aggregating

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Q1': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
    'Q2': ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
    'Q3': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'],
    'Gender': ['F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M'],
    'Age': [22, 35, 20, 54, 42],
    'Dep': ['IT', 'HR', 'IT', 'OPRE', 'OPRE'],
    'Ethnicity': ['W', 'W', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
})

#melt to long form
long_df = df.melt(
    id_vars=['ID','Gender','Age','Dep','Ethnicity'],
    var_name='Question',
    value_name='Response',
)

#convert Gender/Response to categorical to keep 0's
long_df['Response'] = pd.Categorical(long_df['Response'])

#groupby Q/Dep/Response and agg to get M/F/Frac_M/Frac_F
agg_df = long_df.groupby(['Question','Dep','Response']).agg(
    M = ('Gender', lambda g: g.eq('M').sum()),
    F = ('Gender', lambda g: g.eq('F').sum()),
    Frac_M = ('Gender', lambda g: g.eq('M').sum()/len(g)*100),
    Frac_F = ('Gender', lambda g: g.eq('F').sum()/len(g)*100),
).fillna(0)

print(agg_df)
```

[image]

Comment: I got one error "aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'". Can you take a look?

Comment: I copied and pasted the code above exactly and it worked for me with `pd.__version__` of 1.1.5